# jQuery $this vs $(this) in plugin development

Tags: jquery, this, keyword

I was wondering why in so many jquery plugins $(this) is set to be pointing at $this, here is an example, if i have the following two plugins included on a page:

```
(function($) {
   jQuery.fn.pluginOne = function() {
      return this.each(function() {
         $this = $(this); <--
         alert($this);
      });
   };
})(jQuery)

(function($) {
   jQuery.fn.pluginTwo = function() {
      return this.each(function() {
         $this = $(this); <--
         alert($this);
      });
   };
})(jQuery)
```

When i call both plugins on dom ready:

```
$(document).ready({
   $('.myClass').pluginOne();
   $('.myOtherClass').pluginTwo();
});
```

The first plugin will get $this from the second plugin... while it i point $(this) to a local var:

```
(function($) {
   jQuery.fn.pluginTwo = function() {
      return this.each(function() {
         var trigger = $(this); <--
         alert(trigger);
      });
   };
})(jQuery)
```

everything works at it should, of course...

So my question is... when should I use $this?

Thanks

Comment: Just to clarify...

In the above example

$('.myOtherClass').pluginTwo(); will return the first element of the following array:

$('.myClass')

Answer (score 12, accepted):

$this is a standard people use to cache the actual jQuery object $(this) in a variable.

You can call it what you wish, some people like to refer to it as $self.

e.g

```
var $self = $(this)
```

It just helps when you are looking at the code to recognize that it is a jQuery object rather than a normal dom object.

It performs better as you only create one instance of the jQuery variable.

Comment: The point would be that it should be 'var $this' in the above example, then?

Comment: ...of your answer, yes.  Looks to me like the original question related to $this scoping - and, indeed, that the poster is correct (that a variable should be local) and just happens to have two plugins that (a) use $this as a convention, not because it has inherent meaning and (b) don't scope it properly.

Answer (score 9):

`$` is a legitimate character for variable and function names in Javascript. That might be confusing if you're coming from PHP where `$` is used to signify a variable only (took me a while to realise).

- In jQuery, `$` is an alias for the function `jQuery`, which is the main function that handles DOM selection. `$("#header ul.menu")` is the same as `jQuery("#header ul.menu")`. `$` is simply used for brevity.
- `this` is a special term in Javascript (not jQ) meaning the current element (in forms you might see `this.submit()` for example).
- `$(this)` means "call the `jQuery` function with Javascript's `this`".
- `$this` is simply a variable, since `$` is a valid character. You can set `$this` to any value you like and it's completely unrelated to Javascript's `this`. In general I'd suggest NOT using $ for variable names to avoid confusion with the jQuery function. However, it may be useful to use `$var` to denote jQuery objects as opposed to normal Javascript variables.

Answer (score 2):

if you are performing a number of different commands with an element wrapped in a jQuery object, then it is more performant to get the element (as a wrapped set) only once and store that in a local variable

```
var $this = $(this);
// then use $this in your function.
```

Note the use of `var` to locally scope `$this`